# MYSQL query : last N rows + all rows with a specific flag set

Tags: mysql

I need to display on a page, a list of events fetched from the database. The particularity of my query relies on the fact there are different kinds of events within the same table, and then different select conditions/filters.

**Events table's (simplified) schema:**

```
Id INT UNSIGNED AI PK
Type TINYINT
Important BOOL
DateStart DATE
DateStop DATE
```

---

There are 2 types of events to be shown on my home page :

- **News**  : I want only the `last 10 rows` (sorted by date) `where [Type=1]`, (DateStart and DateStop are always the same).
- **Actions** : every rows `where [Type=2] and [Show = true] and [DateStart >= NOW] and [DateStop <= NOW]`, results must NOT count in the News' 10-rows limit.

*All of them (10 last News + shown Actions) being sorted by DateStop ASC.*

Is it possible to do that in a single query ? I thought about UNION but I wonder if there is a simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: you can use union if both the tables have the same column list.

Answer (score 1):

why not union?

```
select tmp.type, tmp.important,tmp.datestart,tmp.datestop 
from                                           -- the 10 last news:
(select top 10 type, important,datestart,datestop
from yourtable
where type=1
order by id desc
union
select type, important,datestart,datestop
from yourtable
where type <>1) tmp   -- in this where clause, add all the other conditions!
order by datestart asc -- or whichever date you want to order by
```

you might need to edit it a little because i am used to sql server from microsoft, thus the syntax might be a little different for mysql.

Comment: Indeed, union seems to be the right way to do it, I wasn't sure if that was the only solution. Thanks for the confirmation !